# PHP: Pass a variable to a file you are including?

Tags: php, php4

I am wondering if there is a way to pass a variable to a file you are including via include()?

I tried this but got an error:

```
include("header_alt.php?img=hey");
```

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: It is terrible idea, imho... ;)

Comment: This can certainly be abused and make your code a mess.  I would most certainly do some pseudo name spacing of variables to avoid collisions and make things a little more maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define your variable in the first file ; for instance, in `temp.php` :

```
<?php
$my_var = 10;

include 'temp-2.php';

die;
?>
```

And use it in the second file ; `temp-2.php` :

```
<?php

var_dump($my_var);

?>
```

And it should work : I'm getting this output, from `temp-2.php` :

```
int 10
```

The query-string syntax, using stuff like `?img=hey` is used when you are requesting some data from a distant server *(like when you are using your browser to surf on websites)*, not when including a file that is on the same server.

Comment: Thanks, for the info. I had been using what you suggested already, just was wondering of a way to make the var only visible from the included page. But ill just continue to do it that same way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) provides a really good mechanism for this sort of thing.  Plus, using Smarty just makes for better php applications.

http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.include.php

> Variables can be passed to included
>   templates as attributes. Any variables
>   explicitly passed to an included
>   template are only available within the
>   scope of the included file. Attribute
>   variables override current template
>   variables, in the case when they are
>   named the same.
>
> All assigned variable values are
>   restored after the scope of the
>   included template is left. This means
>   you can use all variables from the
>   including template inside the included
>   template. But changes to variables
>   inside the included template are not
>   visible inside the including template
>   after the {include} statement.